# Cpanel - 403 al acceder a un recurso

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hosting, cpanel

Tengo un problema en el shared hosting al intentar acceder a un recurso dentro de **public_html/contable/tmp**

Cuando intento acceder a un archivo en ese directorio, me genera el e*rror 403 Forbidden Access to this resource on the server is denied!*

En el log del cpanel me salio lo siguiente:

```
2020-11-22 13:09:24.172080 [INFO] [22332] 
[190.183.80.134:61644-Q:B996F4677DDA92B2-47#APVH_faeppfss.com.ar:443] 
/home/faeppfsscom/public_html/contable/tmp/tmpIZ0mcZ.pdf: access is denied.
```

Revise en el cpanel la configuracion de mi .htaccess y es el siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^faeppfss\.com\.ar$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.faeppfss\.com\.ar$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/faeppfss\.com\.ar\/contable" [R=301,L]
```

El directorio tiene permisos 755. Sin embargo los archivos son creados con permisos 655

Comment: en muchos "shared hosting", existen una serie de pasos a seguir, botones que presionar para no tocar nada de las configuraciones por codigo o texto, asi que te recomiendo que sigas buscando el boton indicado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se resolvio aplicando el siguiente comando cada vez que genero un nuevo archivo

```
chmod("/directorio/fichero", 0755);
```

Esto cambia los permisos asignados originalmente al archivo. Por lo cual se resolvio el error del 403.